# Running Shell Script from PHP Page

Tags: php, ssh, shell-exec

**What I'd like to do:**

When `mydomain.com/index.php` is viewed, run a script, that logs in on another machine (different from the one serving the `index.php`) in the local net of the server and runs a Python script.

**What I have so far:**

In the `index.php` I call

`shell_exec('/var/www/dir/save.sh '.$ARG1.' '.$ARG2);`

The script `save.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set cmd "python /path/to/python_script.py"
set file [lindex $argv 0]
set content [lindex $argv 1]

spawn ssh usr@local_ip "$cmd $file $content"
expect "assword:"
send "PWD\r"
interact
```

I ran `sudo chmod www-data+x save.sh` to enable the PHP-Site to run the command. When I run `sudo -u www-data ./save.sh arg1 arg2` in the terminal, everything works as expected and I can see the output of `python_script.py` (that I print for testing).

However, when calling `index.php` and echoing the output of the `shell_exec`-Call, I see everything up to `user@ip's password:` but *not* the output of `python_script.py` and I can check, that the script has not been invoked on the other machine.

**Any idea, what I'm missing?**
I'm glad for any help! :)

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the quick responses. Sorry for not making myself clear enough.

First of all: This is *not* used for a public/commercial/elaborate website but rather for private fun and `mydomain.com` is locked by `auth_basic`.

My setup: `Server1` is hosting `mydomain.com`. `Server2` is running some stuff for private entertainment, e.g. smart home software and Telegram bots.

What I want to do: When calling `mydomain.com/index.php`, I want to save same parameters (actually just `True` or `False`) to `Server2`, to use them for some of the scripts running there. `Server1` and `Server2` are in the same local network but only `Server1` is reachable from the outside, hence the idea to login via SSH and run a Python-Script.

I appreciate any advise on how to do this in a better way or to make my inteded solution work. :)

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks symcbean for pointing to errors in the script. I have to admit, that I copy pasted it from other stackoverflow threads.

Thanks also to ADyson for pointing out better ways to handle the issue. I will definetly keep them in mind for bigger projects.

In the meantime I was able to get the script running. It is still very basic, does not track excection of the Python script and does not handle errors. Again, I wan't to point out, that I use this for private usage only and `mydomain.com/index.php` will only be up for limited time (it will be an andvent calender and will be taken offline after xmas). But just for completeness sake, here is what I came up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set cmd "python /path/to/python_script.py"
set file [lindex $argv 0]
set content [lindex $argv 1]

spawn ssh usr@local_ip
expect "assword:"
send "PWD\r"
expect "*\$ "
send "$cmd $file $content\r"
expect "*\$*"
send "exit\r"
interact
```

Comment: Be aware that running a script from a PHP script is potentially VERY dangerous, especially if user input is used in constructing the commandline executed.  I'd advise against doing this at all, and if you do then you need to do some very robust validation of user input.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. The purpose is to save same parameters computed from user input on the local machine. Do you have any advise on how to do this in a saver way?

Comment: you say you want to save on the "local" machine? You mean the machine where PHP is running? PHP can do that directly without shell commands or SSH. That would make things safer. And you should write some PHP to validate the input is like what you're expecting before passing it on to any other script or file. But you really need to clarify the use case and the exact situation a bit, before anyone can give you concrete advice about a different design.

Comment: Yikes, trying to keep it short really kills the context … I added a description of my setup in the update.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Worth noting that basic auth is almost no security at all unless you also use HTTPS - otherwise anyone can sniff your password over the insecure connection.

Comment: Anyway potentially a better approach to this would be maybe to simply upload your file to the secondary server via SFTP, or maybe have a second HTTP server running on there and simply make a second request to that from the primary server, send the data, and then have some PHP code on that server do  whatever you need to do there. But symcbean is right below, one reason you're not seeing any output could well be that the process is simply blocking due to the "interact" command, which leads the script to expect keyboard input, which of course you can't give

Comment: ...cont'd...To login automatically via SSH, you'd be better off using key-based login.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable tips. Sorry for beeing a noob :/ The page is indeed running on https thanks to letsencrypt ;)

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the peculiar choices before you got to that point, what exactly were you expecting to happen when the expect script gets to

```
interact
```

?

There is nothing in your shell script to start the python script, nor to track its execution, nor to exit the shell. Meanwhile you PHP code is blocked until the local script exits.

While there are lots of ways of fixing this, I am hesitant to suggest any without a better understanding of why you chose such an elaborate mechanism to handle the invocation.